# Property accessor 'Title' on object 'MyApp.Page3' threw the following exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: gridview, data-binding

I'm getting the following message during the GridView1.DataBind() line:

> Property accessor 'Title' on object 'MyApp.Page3' threw the following exception: 'Object >reference not set to an instance of an object.'

My code-behind looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Page3" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Hedis2013WebApp.Page3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="textboxHMO" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" 
        DataKeyNames="employergroup_id" 
        EmptyDataText="No Data to Show" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:GridView>    
</asp:Content>
```

My code looks like this:

```
protected void LoadGridView()
{
    try
    {
        int
            employergroup_id = (int)Session["Employergroup_id"];

        var db = new pec_prod_on_epic();
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true; //this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;  // EF6
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;
        var qry = from p3 in db.Page3 where p3.employergroup_id == employergroup_id select p3;
        var result = qry.ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = result;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of my master page looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Hedis2013WebApp.SiteMaster" %>
<%--<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Portal</title>
```

I can't think of any change I might have made to bring this about. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the following line of code:

```
var qry = from p3 in db.Page3 where p3.employergroup_id == employergroup_id select p3;
```

I think you mistakenly deleted the word (SELECT,DELETE OR UPDATE) in the above query. Let me know if it solved your problem.